# PySide6 QSqlTableModel не видит одну из таблиц QSqlDatabase

Tags: python-3.x, ms-access, odbc, pyside6, qsqltablemodel

В базе данных есть несколько таблиц. Все открываются замечательно, кроме одной.

[image: Структура таблицы messages]

```
db = QSqlDatabase("QODBC")
db.setDatabaseName(r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\...\file.accdb")
db.open(username, password)
model = QSqlTableModel(db=db)
model.setTable("messages")
model.select()
```

Выводит `False`.

Команда model.lastError().text() выводит:

```
'Unable to find table messages'
```

При том, что команда db.tables() выводит:

```
['messages', 'table1', 'table2', ..., 'tableN']
```

*Непосредственно через MS Access эта таблица открывается*

Уже пытался и через цикл открыть. Ключевое слово в db.tables() находилось, но конкретно таблицу 'messages' QSqlTableModel не видит.

Попытался сменить MS Access на версию 2016 года. Думал, вдруг какой-то определённый тип из MS Access 2019 конфликтует со старым драйвером. Не помогло.

Думал скачать более новый драйвер, а такого не нашёл.
Пытался покопаться в реестре... Тоже ничего не нашёл.

Пожалуйста, помогите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, я разобрался в проблеме методом тыка. Я изначально был прав по поводу конфликта драйвера с типом данных bigint, вот только не хватало нескольких дополнительных действий.

По всей видимости, когда вы пытаетесь поставить тип данных bigint и сохранить, Access предупреждает вас, что из-за него БД могут не поддерживать старые версии, а вы всё равно сохраняете, он автоматически ставит минимальную поддерживаемую версию, что-ли?

Помогло разделение данных, предварительно поменяв тип данных bigint на другой тип данных. Работа с базами данных->Перемещение данных->База данных Access.